# Vertical Spacing using \subcaption package

Tags: subcaption

I have a simple problem. I'm trying to add a little bit of vertical spacing between the top two and bottom two subfigures. Here's my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t0_5.jpg}
  \caption{t = 0.5 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ChRe100t1.jpg}
  \caption{t = 1.0 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t1_5.jpg}
   \caption{t = 1.5 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}%
\begin{subfigure}{.5\textwidth}
\centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t2.jpg}
   \caption{t = 2.0 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{y vs. u}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You could insert the instructions `\par\bigskip` between the second and third subfigure to create a bit of extra vertical space between the two sets of subfigures. If `\bigskip` is too much for your taste, try using `\medskip`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t0_5.jpg}
  \caption{t = 0.5 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ChRe100t1.jpg}
  \caption{t = 1.0 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\par\bigskip % force a bit of vertical whitespace
\begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
   \centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t1_5.jpg}
   \caption{t = 1.5 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\begin{subfigure}{.49\textwidth}
\centering
   \includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t2.jpg}
   \caption{t = 2.0 s and Re = 100}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{y vs. u}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wouldn't `\par\bigskip` be (conceptually, but not only) better?

Comment: @egreg - thanks for the suggestion. I've modified the code.

Answer (score 2):

The same result (as Mico) can be obtained with less typing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} % omit 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{stackengine}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t0_5.jpg}}{(a) t = 0.5 s and Re = 100}~~~~~~
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{ChRe100t1.jpg}}{(b) t = 1.0 s and Re = 100}
\par\bigskip
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t1_5.jpg}}{(c) t = 1.5 s and Re = 100}~~~~~~
\stackunder{\includegraphics[scale=0.2]{CHRe100t2.jpg}}{(d) t = 2.0 s and Re = 100}
\caption{y vs. u}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An interesting solution. Real quick: Will this solution allow the creation of hyperlinks to each of the four subfigure environments (assuming, of course, that each one is given its own `\label`)?

Comment: @Mico.  I don't use `hyperref` so I can't answer with authority, but the `stackengine` package makes no special provisions for it.  Thus, I would guess that `\label{}` would get you to the figure, but not the subfigure.

Comment: @Mico A little late in reply, but this answer, http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170304/horizontal-alignment-of-subfigure-edges/170306#170306, shows how `hyperref` can be incorporated with `stackengine` to handle subfigure hotlinks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the `\belowcaptionskip` length and use `\par` to denote new rows.

```
\begin{figure}
  \newcommand{\subfigurehspace}{.49\linewidth}
  \setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0.5\baselineskip}
  \centering
  % %%% ROW 1 %%%
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigurehspace}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{1.png}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigurehspace}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{2.png}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \par
  % %%% ROW 2 %%% 
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigurehspace}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{3.png}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
  \hfill
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{\subfigurehspace}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{4.png}
    \caption{}
  \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
```

If you don't want additional spacing after the last row, you can reset `\belowcaptionskip` to its original value before the final row. This should probably not be necessary, though.

Comment: The `\par` is not necessary. Lines will also break automatically, and have the desired vertical spacing until the next row.