# Horizontal alignment of subfigure edges

Tags: horizontal-alignment, memoir, subfloats

I am using the memoir class and I have two subfigures of different width that I would like to lay out vertically. Ideally, these two subfigures should be aligned so that

- The widest subfigure is centered (to `\textwidth`).
- Other subfigures have their right edge aligned to the right edge of the widest subfigure.

How can I achieve this? The code below can work as a starting point.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\subbottom[]{\framebox{Narrow subfig}}
\\
\subbottom[]{\framebox{Wide subfigure with lots of stuff}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I first tried using a minipage inside the figure environment, where content inside the minipage was right justified. The problem was setting the width of the minipage to exactly the width of the widest subfigure; if that problem has a solution, I think that would work.

One solution would be to compile the figure as a separate file using `standalone`. I wish to avoid that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `varwidth` environment from the package with the same name.

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum,varwidth}
\newsubfloat{figure}

\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\raggedleft
\subbottom[]{\framebox{Narrow subfig}}
\\
\subbottom[]{\framebox{Wide subfigure with lots of stuff}}
\end{varwidth}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Simple, and exactly the effect I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: I am afraid I was a little too quick: The subfigures contain tikz figures. I get incorrect alignment for those, and the warning "Package varwidth Warning: Failed to reprocess entire contents". Is varwidth not applicable for tikz pictures somehow?

Comment: @josteinb Worked fine here with a very simple `tikzpicture` (just a rectangle), can you incorporate the `tikzpicture`s in your MWE? The following worked: `\begin{varwidth}{\linewidth}
\raggedleft
\subbottom[]{\framebox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (2,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\\
\subbottom[]{\framebox{\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) rectangle (5,1);
\end{tikzpicture}}}
\end{varwidth}`

Comment: I also made it work in the MWE with a simple tikzpicture. However, the "real" figure still causes problems. I will have to do some more testing to figure out exactly what is causing the problem.

Comment: @josteinb You also could post the code of a troublesome `tikzpicture` if you like.

Comment: @josteinb Any luck making a new MWE?

Comment: No, unfortunately. It would have required some sort of bisection, which I just can't find time for at the moment. Aligning the tikzpictures proved to be easier by simply creating one large tikzpicture and specifying the alignment manually.

Answer (score 5):

I took my answer at [Looking for three images on top of each other with text underneath each](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169541/looking-for-three-images-on-top-of-each-other-with-text-underneath-each/169546#169546), changed the figure (rule) widths to make them different, and added a `[r]` optional specifier to the `\Shortstack` for right alignment.  The cited answer explains how the use of the `\subcaptionbox` variant in conjunction with a package like `stackengine` can allow great flexibility in the figure layout.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]
  \centering
  \def\figa{\rule{1.5in}{1.1in}}
  \def\figb{\rule{1.2in}{1.5in}}
  \def\figc{\rule{1in}{0.9in}}
  \def\capa{subfig a caption}
  \def\capb{subfig b caption}
  \def\capc{subfig c caption which may be longer}
  \savestack{\capfiga}{\subcaptionbox{\capa\label{fg:a}}{\figa}}
  \savestack{\capfigb}{\subcaptionbox{\capb\label{fg:b}}{\figb}}
  \savestack{\capfigc}{\subcaptionbox{\capc\label{fg:c}}{\figc}}
  \setstackgap{S}{12pt}
  \Shortstack[r]{\capfiga\\ \capfigb\\ \capfigc}%
  \caption{This is my figure\label{fg:}}
\end{figure}
In figure \ref{fg:}, \ref{fg:a}, \ref{fg:b} and \ref{fg:c}...
\end{document}
```

[image]

To amplify on the flexibility I tout, one merely add the specifier `\def\useanchorwidth{T}` anywhere prior to the `\Shortstack` and the bottom (narrow) image of the stack will be centered (rather than the widest image), with the others protruding left:

[image]